# Breakpoints not hit in an Xamarin.android example

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm struggling with understanding the example of the ViewPager Indicator of Xamarin, because i can't set Breakpoints, working as they should do. while debugging, those get simply ignored... well i could read all the text, but there is so many i haven't seen before, i dont quite understand how this whole thing work. I'm a beginner, and want to learn, but without seeing whats going on in examples i can't do/learn anything. Is there anything i'm missing to do, so i can set working breakpoints?

Comment: Which version of Xamarin.Android are you using?

Comment: That is a very old version. Get the latest one.

Comment: I've seen, that there are newer ones, but my VS is configured to inform me about new updates and even if i hit check now, there is no new version to download, so do i have to deinstall the old one and install the new one?`

Comment: Grab the latest from the store page after you have logged in: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem, breakpoints are working now... but tell me, is it normal, that the highest settable version of android in the layout-designer is 4.0.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breakpoint issues were fixed in a newer version of Xamarin.Android, which you can get from the [store page](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads).

Comment: What version are you using right now?
I have the same problem in 4.6.00049

Comment: 4.6 is ancient. Use the latest 4.8.xxxxx